# How to get the assembly name of the parent project in .NET?

Tags: .net, dll, reflection

I have a solution with one ASP.NET application and a class library project. The ASP.NET application is using the class library project.

I want to check the assembly name of the ASP.NET application inside the class library.

Actually I have an MVC application with a separate Model project. The MVC application uses Model project. I have created a `RemoteWithServerSideAttribute` in an another project and used it in the model. In the `RemoteWithServerSideAttribute` class the I need the controller assembly information to invoke a method. If I use `Assembly.GetCallingAssembly` I am getting `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` assembly info because the `RemoteWithServerSideAttribute` is inherited from `RemoteAttribute` inside the `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations`.

What I want is to get the assembly information of the MVC project.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but you can make use of [System.Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection(v=vs.110).aspx) to get either the Executing Assembly information or the Entry Assembly information.

So if you are calling a method in the ClassLibrary from the Web Application, then;

`System.Reflection.Asembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name` will give you the name of the Class Library

`System.Reflection.Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().GetName().Name` will give you the name of the Web Application.

Comment: thanks for the replay. its fine. Please check the above comment there I have explained what I want exactly...

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `Assembly.GetCallingAssembly` [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getcallingassembly(v=vs.110).aspx).

From it you can get it's [FullName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.fullname(v=vs.110).aspx) or `GetName()`, for example.

Comment: The links are Polish. Would be better if you could post English links.

Comment: Actually I have an MVC application with a separate Model project. The MVC application uses Model project. I have created a RemoteWithServerSideAttribute in an another project and used it in the model. In the RemoteWithServerSideAttribute class the I need the controller assembly information to invoke a method. If I use Assembly.GetCallingAssembly  I am getting System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations assembly info because the RemoteWithServerSideAttribute is inherited from RemoteAttribute inside the System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations. I want to get the assembly information of the MVC project?

Comment: www.codeproject.com/Articles/361113/Extending-the-MVC-RemoteAttribute-to-validate-ser?msg=4910821#xx4910821
Please refer the above link. I am trying to separate the RemoteServerSide attribute from the mvc class in to a separate class